# kmeans with big data

Tags: r, bigdata, k-means

I want to cluster big data matrix (5 million X 512) with kmeans into 5000 centers.
I'm using R in order not to blow my memory with this matrix.

I wrote this code to convert txt matrix into xdf and then cluster:

```
rxTextToXdf(inFile = inFile, outFile = outFile)
vars <- rxGetInfo(outFile,getVarInfo=TRUE)
myformula <- as.formula(paste("~", paste(names(vars$varInfo), collapse = "+"), sep=""))

clust <- rxKmeans(formula = myformula, data = outFile,numClusters = 5000, algorithm =     "lloyd", overwrite = TRUE)
write.table(clust$centers, file = centersFiletxt, sep=",", row.names=FALSE,    col.names=FALSE)
```

But it has been running for a week now. Any ideas how to make it faster?

Comment: Looks like you're using Revolution R and not open source R. Difficult to reproduce then. What are the spec of your computer ?

Comment: intel i7 3630 2.4GHz 8 GB Ram 500 Gb Hard disk windows x64

Comment: I don't use Revolution and the only advice I can you is to try `bigmemory` + `biganalytics::bigkmeans` but to my knowledge it doesn't work on windows (unless someone correct me) so if you have access to other machine...

Comment: You could also think of randomly downsampling your data by a factor 10 or 100 to see if you really need those 5,000 groups.

Comment: Python's Scikit-Learn has an implementation of [mini-batch k-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html) that is really efficient - it works by just taking a random subset of say 100 samples, and clustering that, and iterating, using the centres from the previous iteration as the initialisation for the next iteration. The results are not identical, but they're [very close](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mini-batch-k-means). I would really like to know if there is a an R version of this algorithm.

Answer (score 10):

1. Do you really need 5000 clusters? k-means performance scales with the number of clusters, so you're hurting yourself quite a bit with such a high number of clusters there. If you can stand to reduce the number of clusters, that will help a lot.
2. Are you sure you need all 512 dimensions? If you can trim out or combine some of those dimensions that could also help. Have you tried running PCA on your data? Maybe you could try running k-means on just the top 10 components or something like that.
3. Does it have to be k-means? You could try other algorithms like hierarchical clustering or self-organizing maps and see if those don't perform faster. I'd recommend taking a sample of your data (maybe N=100K) and speed test a few clustering algorithms on that.
4. Revolution R is definitely supposed to be way faster than base R, but it's still R. K-means is a very simple algorithm to implement: maybe try finding/coding an implementation a bit closer to the metal, like C/C++ or FORTRAN.
5. Are you tracking your memory usage? Frankly, I suspect you already *have* blown your memory. At a single iteration, you're asking your computer to build a distance matrix between each of your 5 million points to each of your 5000 centroids *in 512 dimensions*. This means your distance matrix will be 5M x 5K x 512, or 1.28e13 records (multiply this by the bit encoding of your data type). You only have 6.9e10 bits of RAM. Unless Revolution R is doing something very sneaky, there's simply no possibility of approaching this problem on your hardware unless you buy way, way more RAM. Even with 64 GB, you're still several orders of magnitude short of a single k-means iteration.
6. You say you're using R in order to not blow your memory usage: maybe Revolution R is different, but conventional R does *everything* in memory, and as I described above, this problem isn't really going to be tractable on conventional hardware. You should consider renting some time on a more powerful computing cluster like amazon EC2.
7. k-means is one of those algorithms that's "embarassingly paralellizable." If you rent out server space, you could run this on a hadoop cluster and that should help a lot.
8. What are you trying to accomplish here? 5000 clusters is a lot. What is the anticipated meaning of your 5000 clusters? I suspect that the real solution here isn't a faster kmeans implementation or more powerful hardware, but rethinking your problem and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: There are functions in R like rxkmeans that write and load data from files on the hard drive, that way i'm able to bypass the memory problem. I have 500 Gb hard drive and it's more then enough for the calculations. The problem is with run time duration. I don't want to wait a month for those calculations.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your outfile (or whatever database R is using to push these calculations to disk) is both populated and continues to be modified? I can't help but suspect that R is frozen. Is there an output log file you can reference to confirm that this is in fact still chugging away and not stuck on the first iteration?

Comment: Item #8 is the most important question of the lot, and is related to #1. If you look into some of the metrics like AIC or BIC you might well find that after 5 or 10 clusters you are not adding anything to the quality of your solution. Unless the system from which you have data really has 5,000 discrete states, you may just be pushing electrons around for no real benefit.

Comment: answers 1 and 2 are just classic... what a hoot

Answer (score 5):

If you bought RevoR you also paid for support. Why not ask them?

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a sample to represent your data, you could cluster the sample first and then use a classification technique  to train a model on it and then predict on chunks of the remaining data to assign clusters.

Training the model will also tell you which variables are not significant and you can reduce the dimensionality that way.

Why increase computation complexity with 5m rows x 512 features x 5000 clusters when you can get more insights by dealing piece meal with the problem?